# Heroku Doesn't Seem to Update in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade

When prompted to check the version of Heroku in this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli (under the troubleshooting section), I can't use the simple `heroku update command`, I have to use the
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade heroku` entry which I understand. The issue is that it says I'm not up to date with my version as we see directly below. This is the exact output:

```
› Warning: heroku update available from 7.0.92 to 7.0.93
heroku/7.0.92 linux-x64 node-v10.4.0
```

Clearly it's indicating that my program isn't up to date on the first line and  that my program can be upgraded to 7.0.93. Like I said, I enter the appropriate command to upgrade and when I enter `heroku version` it outputs that same message. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this issue? I don't know what's wrong and I've uninstalled the program and started from scratch numerous times and still can't figure out the issue.

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu in the Oracle VM.

Comment: @dessert I believe I used the snap at the top, right below the Mac and Windows options and once it didn't work I think I tried the snap option. If you had to guess,  what would be your best guess as to how to navigate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

On my Lubuntu 16.04 machine, I tried the [`snap` package installastion](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install), the [script installation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#ubuntu-debian-apt-get) (which basically adds a PPA and installs from it) and the [standalone installation from tarball](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#tarballs). The `snap` package didn’t install, both the other installations left me with version 7.0.92 as you describe. In the case of the PPA, you can trust the system to provide you with the latest version the PPA owner – https://www.heroku.com in this case – provides. As even the tarball version doesn’t provide the obviously current version 7.0.93 (yet), I assume the new version has just not been made available via tarballs and the PPA yet, but probably will be shortly. If you installed `heroku` with the script, your usual package updates covers `heroku` as well. You don’t need to do anything special to receive updates for the package, and the version the PPA provides is probably fine.

Comment: You da man, thank you! For script you mean the `curl` option,  yes?

Comment: @erik You’re welcome! With “script installation” I mean the `curl` command in the [“Ubuntu / Debian apt-get” session](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#ubuntu-debian-apt-get). The `curl` command in the [“Standalone installation” session](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone-installation) basically just downloads and extracts the tarball.

Comment: it's been a busy last few days but just to clarify, you recommend uninstalling and trying the curl version and even if it doesn't update right away it eventually will when Heroku releases it's compatible equivalent?

Comment: I also know you mentioned the curl option but to also be clear, you are recommending the Debian/Ubuntu version over the Standalone? And if it is the Debian/Ubuntu version do I enter the 'npm' command directly below it?

Comment: @erik Yes, simply because the PPA installation (“Debian/Ubuntu apt-get”) provides you with updates via `apt` while the standalone doesn’t. You just need to run `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` to install Heroku this way.